# Control Theory Integrator Phase Shift

Tags: math, integrator

Guess I should know the answer, but I can't come up with a good explanation.

I always have to remember which sign cos and sin have after integration/differentiation. I usually do this by thinking of a diagram like the one in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023105/mnemonic-for-derivative-integral-of-sin-x-and-cos-x).

Today I thought I should memorize this, since it's so useful. You just need to draw the two axis with +- sin cos. The only thing to memorize would then be which direction is integration and which direction is differentiation.

But this is the part which I just realized is counter intuitive. From control theory one would expect to be an integrator a rotation of -90° (Phase shift of an integrator).

What's wrong? Why can't I use this to memorize this?

EDIT 1:

I might ask in another way. A integrator is a "1/s block" in control theory and a differentiator a "s block". "s" corresponds to jw. Multiplication by jw is a 90° rotation counter clock wise. 
Why is the rotation direction in the diagram on the other post not the same?

At least the end up in the same result. A phase shift of -90° is a shift to the right. This makes a sin a -cos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way (to me) is that with a differentiator, the rising positive slope of a sine wave input (as it passes through zero) produces a positive output peak. When the sine wave is falling, a negative peak is produced.

When integrating (accumulating), if the input sinwave is passing through zero, there is no change in the integrators output (nothing to accumulate). This corresponds with a positive or negative peak in the output and, if the input is rising through zero then the integrator's output (although flat when the sine input is exactly at zero) will begin to rise in a positive direction: -

[image]

A significant problem with regular op-amp integrators is that they also invert the signal and this leads to an extra confusion.

Comment: Thank you! I see your point. Thats exactly the way I usually think of it. However I looked for a different way of seeing it. You may check my EDIT.